# A data structure from Repository to serve all purposes?

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

I need help with something I can’t get my head wrapped around regarding the *Repository* and *Service/Use-case* pattern (part of *DDD* design) I want to implement in my next (Laravel PHP) project.

All seems clear. Just one part of DDD that is confusing is the data structures from repositories. People seem to choose data structures the Repository should return (arrays or entities) but it all has disadvantages. One of which is performance looking at my experiences in the past. And one is which you don’t have interfaces for simple data structures (array or simple object attributes).

I’ll start with explaining the experience I have with a previous project. This project had flaws but some good strengths I learned from and like to see in my new project but with solving some design mistakes.

**Previous experience**

In the past I’ve build a website that was API Centric using the Kohana framework and Doctrine 2 ORM (data mapper pattern). The flow looked like this:

*Website controller → API client (HMVC calls) → API controller → Custom Repository → Doctrine 2 ORM native Repository/Entity-manager*

My custom Repository returned plain arrays using Doctrine2 DQL. Doctrine2 recommends array result data for read only operations. And yes, it made my site nice and light. The API controller just converted the array data to JSON. Simple as that.

In the past my company created projects relying fully on loaded Doctrine2 entities and it’s something we regretted due to performance.

My REST API supported queries like
`/api/users?include_latest_adverts=2&include_location=true`
on the users resource. The API controller passed `include_location` to the repository which directly included the location relation. The controller read `latest_adverts=2` and called the adverts repository to get the latest 2 adverts of each user. Arrays were returned.

For example first user array:

```
[
    name
    avatar
    adverts [
        advert 1 [
            name
            price 
        ]
        advert 2 [
            …. 
        ]
    ]
]
```

This proved to be very successful. My whole website was using the API. It would be very easy to to add a new client because the API was perfectly in production already using oauth. The whole website runs on it.

But this design had flaws too. My controller still contained A LOT of logic for validation, mailing, params or filters like `has_adverts=true` to get users with adverts only. It would mean that if I created a new port, like a total new CLI interface, I would have to duplicate alot of these controllers due to all the validation etc. But no duplication if I would create a new client. So at least one problem was solved :-)

My admin panels were completely coupled to the doctrine2 repository/entity-manager to speed up development (sort of). Why? Because my API had fat controllers with special functionality for the website only (special validation, mailing for registering etc). I would have to redo work or refactor a lot. So decided to use the Entities directly to still have some sort clear way of writing code instead of rewriting all my API controllers and move them to Services (for site & admin) for instance. Time was an issue in fixing my design mistakes.

For my next project I want all code to go through my own custom repositories and services. One flow for good separation.

**New project (using DDD ideas) and dilemma with data structures**

While I like the idea of being API centric, I don’t want my next project to be API centric in core because I think the same functionality should be available without the HTTP protocol in between. I want to design the core using DDD ideas.

But I liked the idea using a layer that just talked as a API and returns simple arrays. The perfect base for any new port, including my own frontend. My idea is to consider my Service classes as the API interface (return the array data), do the validation etc. I could have Services specially for the website (registering) and plain services used by the Admin or background processes. In some admin cases a Service would not be required anyway for simple CRUD editing, I could just use Repositories directly. Controllers would be very thin. With this creating a real REST API would just be a matter to create new controllers using the same Services my frontend controller classes do.

For internal logic like business rules it would be useful to have Entities (clear interfaces) instead of arrays from repositories. This way I could benefit from defining some methods that did some logic based on attributes. BUT If I would be using Doctrine2 and my repositories would always return Entities my application would suffer a big performance hit!!

One data structure ensures performance but no clear interfaces, the other ensures clear interfaces but bad performance when using a Data Pattern pattern like Doctrine 2 (now or in the future). Also I could end up with two data types which would be confusing.

I was thinking something similar to this flow:

*Controller (thin) → UserService (incl. validation) → UserRepository (just storage) → Eloquent ORM*

Why Eloquent instead of Doctrine2? Because I want to stick a bit to what’s common within the Laravel framework and community. So I could benefit from third party modules, for example to generate admin interfaces or similar based on models (bypassing my DDD rules). Other than using third party modules, I would design my core stuff so switching should always be easy and not affect data structure choices or performance.

Eloquent is an activerecord pattern. So I would be tempted to convert this data to POPO’s like Doctrine2 entities are. But nope... as said above, with doctrine2 real models would make the system very fat. So I fall back to simple arrays again. Knowing this would work for both and any other implementation in the future.

But it feels bad always rely on arrays. Especially when creating internal business rules. A developer would have to guess values on arrays, have no autocompletion in his IDE, could not have special methods like in Entity classes. But making two ways of dealing with data feels bad too. Or I am just too perfectionist ;) I want ONE clear data structure for all!

Building interfaces and POPO’s would mean a lot of duplicate work. I would need to convert an Eloquent model (just a table mapper, not entity) to an entity object implementing this interface. All is extra work. And eventually my last layer would be just like a API, thus converting it to arrays again. Which is extra work too. Arrays seem the deal again.

It seemed so easy reading up into DDD and Hexagonal. It seems so logic! But in reality I struggle with this one simple issue trying to stick to OOP principles. I want to use arrays because it’s the only way to be 100% sure I am not depended on any model choice and querying choice from my ORM regarding performance etc and don't have duplicate work in converting to arrays for views or an API. But there's no clear contract on how a user array could look. I want to speed up my project using these patterns, not slow them down :-) So not an option to have many converters.

Now I read a lot of topics. One makes POPO’s & interfaces that conform proper entities like Doctrine2 could return, but with all the extra work for Eloquent. Switching to Doctrine2 should be fairly easy, but would impact performance so bad or one would need to convert Doctrine2 array data to these own entity interfaces. Others choose to return simple arrays.

One convinces people to use Doctrine2 instead of  Eloquent, but they leave out the fact that Doctrine2 is heavy and you really need to use array results for read only operations.

We design repositories to be changeable right? Not because it’s “nice” by design only. So how could we rely on full Entities if it has such big impact on performance or duplicate work? Even when using Doctrine2 only (coupled) this same issue would arise due to its performance!

All ORM implementations would be able to return arrays, thus no duplicate work there. Good performance. But we miss clear contracts. And we don’t have interfaces for arrays or class attributes (as a workaround)... Ugh ;)

**Do I just miss a missing block in our programming languages? Interfaces on simple data structures??**

Is it wise to make all arrays and have advanced business logic talk to these arrays? Thus no classes with clear interfaces. Any precalculated data (normally would be returned by an Entity method) would be within an array key defined the Service class. if not wise, what’s the alternative considering all of the above?

I would really appreciate if someone with great experience in this “domain” considering performance, different ORM implementations, etc could tell me how he/she has dealt with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are dealing with is something similiar I'm struggling with. The solution I'm thinking works best is:

1. **Entities/Repositories**

   - Use and pass around Entities **always** when performing Write operations (Creating things, Updating things, Deleting things, and complex combinations thereof).
   - Sometimes you may use Entities when doing Read operations (when you anticipate the Read might need to be used for a Write soon after...ie. *->findById* is soon followed by *->save*).
   - Anytime you are working with an Entity (whether it be Write or Read), the Repositories need to be the place to go. You should be able to tell new developers that they can only persist to the database through Entities and the Repository.
   - The Entities will have properties that represent some Domain Object (many times they represent a database table with the fields of a table, but not always). They will also contain the domain logic/rules with them (ie. validation, calculations) so they are not anemic. You may additionally have some domain services if your Entities need help interacting with other Entities (need to trigger other events), or you just need an additional place to handle some extra domain logic (perform Repository calls to check for some unique conditions).
   - Your Repositories will solely be for working with Entities. The Repositories could accept Entities and do some persistence work with them. Or they could accept just some parameters, and do some reading/fetching into full Entities.
   - Some Repositories will know how to save some Domain Objects that are more complex than others. Perhaps an Entity that has a property which contains a list of other Entities that need to be saved along side the main entity (you can dive deeper into learning about Aggregate roots if you want).
   - The interfaces to Repositories rest in your Domain layer, but not the actual implementations of those Repositories. That way you can have an Eloquent version or whatever.
2. **Other Queries (Table Data Gateway)**

   - These queries won't work with Entities. They'll just be accepting parameters and returning things like Arrays or POPO's (Plain Old PHP Objects).
   - Many times you will need to perform Reads that do not return nicely into a single Entity. These Reads are typically more for reporting (not for CRUD-like operations, like Reading a user into an edit form that is eventually submitted and saved). For example, you might have a report that is 200 rows of JOINed data. If you used the Repositiory and tried to return large deep objects (with all the relationships populated, or even lazy-loaded) then you are going to have performance issues. Instead, use the Table Data Gatway pattern. You are just displaying data and not really needing OOP power here. The outputted data could however contain ID's, which through the UI could be used to initiate calls to Repository persistence methods.
   - As you are developing your app, when you come across the need for a new Read/Report query, create a new method in some class somewhere in your Table Data Gatway folder. You may find you have already created a similar query, so see how you can consolidate the other query. Use some parameters if necessary to make the gateway method's queries more flexible in particular ways (ie. columns to select, sort order, pagination, etc.). **Don't make your queries too flexible though**, this is where query builders/ORMs go wrong! You need to constrain your queries to a certain extent to where if you need to replace them (perhaps a different database engine) then you can easily perceive what the allowed variations  are  and aren't. It's up to you to find the right balance between flexibility (so you have more DRY code) and constraints (so you can optimize/replace queries later).
   - You can create services in your Domain to handle receiving parameters, then passing them to the Table Data Gateway, and then receiving back arrays to do some more mutating on. This will keep your Domain logic in the domain (and out of the infrastructure/persistence layer of the Repository & Table Data Gateway).
   - Again, just like the Repository, use interfaces in your domain services so that the implementation details stay out of your Domain layer, and resides in the actual Table Data Gateway folder.